# how to concatenate Login, pwd and @server variables?

Tags: shell, shell-script, ksh, sqlplus

how to concatenate Login, pwd and @server variables ??
ex:

```
   export Login_va="Login"
   export pwd_va="pwd"
   export server_var="@server"

       echo whenever sqlerror exit | sqlplus $Login/$Passwd$@SERVER @"TABLE1.sql"

echo 'return code : ' $?
```

any help?

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: you'll get a lot closer by using the same variable names in both places...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly braces

```
export Login_va="Login"
export pwd_va="pwd"
export server_var="@server"

echo whenever sqlerror exit | sqlplus "${Login_va}${pwd_va}${server_va}" @"TABLE1.sql"

echo 'return code : ' $?
```

See a little explanation about `curly braces` in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/bash-when-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables)